# What's the best way to pass data into a Flex chart from a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache-flex

Quite a few methods exist for passing data into a Flex binary from a Rails application.  Right now, I'm using the old e4x resultFormat with a xml.erb template.  I've done AMF before, but I feel like inlining parameters into the embed itself is a better solution because you don't have to wait for the browser to load a swf binary and the binary to make a web request.

Taking all of that into account, what is the best practice for rendering a Flex widget with a Rails back-end these days?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you shouldn't use Flex at all. Flex is great for writing applications that load and display data, but is a huge overhead if you just want to display charts. If you're worried about delivering the SWF and the data in two separate responses, you should be worrying about the 200-300 K overhead of the Flex framework.

Go with something more lightweight like [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) and deliver the JavaScript code that generates the charts along with the data. I don't think Flex is a suitable platform for what you want.

Comment: Google analytics and finance use SWF-based charts (not sure if they're Flash or Flex though).  It seems like SWF charts do a better job with larger volumes of data than JS ones.

Answer (score 1):

If the chart is just a graphic you are placing amidst normal html content, your solution of custom compiling the swf may be a good one.  Of course you should still explore alternatives like Theo's suggestion.

If your whole application is flash, it's a toss-up.  If it is fastest to simply import a swf, go ahead.  However, if you need to make things any more interactive, use the data elsewhere, or fetch new data, it would probably be best to use xml templates as you are, or the [ActiveRecord::Base#to_xml](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.1.0/doc/index.html?a=M001377&name=to_xml) method if you're lazy.

Comment: I'm using a dataprovider with to_xml now.  But, I'm wondering when it is more appropriate to just parametrize all the data into an embed tag versus making another http call.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, are you going to want the charts to be 'live', as in get updated in real-time when data changes? If so then using AMF with a Flex native RemoteObject gives you plenty of polling options, you can also just use a simpler Flex native HTTPService.

Read about them both here: [Flex Actionscript 3.0 Documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html)